# ERRO: Função para inserir palavra em cadeia de caracteres

Tags: java

Escrevi uma função para receber uma cadeia de caracteres, um carácter e uma posição .

```
  /**
    * Funcao para inserir um simbolo em certa posicao valida ENTRE outros
    * em dada cadeia de caracteres.
    * @param a - cadeia de caracteres
    * @param b - character a inserir
    * @param c - posicao de insercao
    * @return cadeia de caracteres com character inserido.
    *
    * Teste:
    *   Para a = "palvra", b = 'A' e c = 3
    *   retorna palAvra
    *
    *   Para a = "algorimos", b = 'T' e c = 6
    *   retorna algoriTmos
    */
  public static String original (String a, char b, int c){

    String nova;
    int tamanho;
    int i;

    if (a == null) {

      nova = ("Erro: string nula.");

    } else {

      tamanho = a.length();

      // e' necessario que a string tenha ao menos duas letras para inserir
      // caracteres entre a cadeia de caracteres
      if (tamanho < 2) {

        nova = ("Erro: tamanho da palavra invalido.");

      } else {

        // para que a posicao seja valida ela precisa estar entre o
        // primeiro e o ultimo caracter da cadeia de caracteres.
        if (c > 0 && c < tamanho) {

          nova = ("Erro: posicao invalida.");

        } else {

          nova = "";

          for (i = 0 ; i < tamanho ; i++) {

            if (i != c) {

              nova = nova + a.charAt(i);

            } else {

              nova = nova + b + a.charAt(i);

            } // fim do if else

          } // fim do for

        } // fim do if else

      } // fim do if else

    } // fim do if else

    return (nova);

  } // fim do original



  /**
    * metodo para testar a funcao original
    */
  public static void teste_01(){

    String n;
    String a;
    char b;
    int c;

    a = IO.readString("\nPalavra: ");
    b = IO.readchar("Caracter: ");
    c = IO.readint("Posicao: ");

    n = original(a, b, c);

    IO.println("\nString: " + n);

  } // fim do teste_01
```

A função esta funcionando ok, exceto pelo fato de não estar retornando o erro para posições invalidas (quando eu coloco uma posição maior ou igual ao tamanho da string), não consegui entender o por que.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (c > 0 && c < tamanho) {

      nova = ("Erro: posicao invalida.");

    }
```

no if acima ocorre a verificação de a posição é correta , se a posição for correta, esse trecho de código é executado. O Problema e que seu código de inserção do caractere deveria vim nesta parte, e não else